# HTTPS POST working successfully but variables come up null

Tags: php, ios, swift, post, server

The code I've posted here is a shortened versions with just the essentials to the issue. When put through rigorous error testing, it appears that there are no issues either within the request, within the server, or within the return code, except for the fact that the response from the server says "Function": null instead of "Function": "addUser" as it should. Is there something I'm doing wrong on either end? It just seems to not be recognizing the posted variables, but I've used this code numerous times in other apps and servers and it seems to be failing here for some reason I cannot see. Thank you for any assistance.

Here is my PHP on the server:

```
<?php
   $t = $_POST["function"];
   $do = array("Success"=>true, "Function"=> $t);
   echo json_encode($do);
?>
```

Here is the swift I'm using to make the request:

```
  let params = ["function": "addUser"] as [String: AnyObject]?


    fetchData("https://pdt.pitchprogress.net/SamplePHP.php", token: nil, parameters: params, method: "POST", onCompletion: { (success, data) -> Void in
        if success {
            do {
                let json = try JSON(data: data!)
                if json["Success"].boolValue == true {
                    print("success!")
                    print(json.description)
                    print(json["Function"].stringValue)
               }
              }      
             }       
             })       




func fetchData(_ feed:String,token:String? = nil,parameters:[String:AnyObject]? = nil,method:String? = nil, onCompletion:@escaping (_ success:Bool,_ data:Data?)->Void){

DispatchQueue.main.async {


    if let unwrapped_url = URL(string: feed){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: unwrapped_url)

        if let parm = parameters {
            if let data = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parm, options:[])) as Data? {

                request.httpBody = data
                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.setValue("\(data.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

            }
        }

        if let unwrapped_method = method {
            request.httpMethod = unwrapped_method
        }

        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

        let taskGetCategories = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) -> Void in

            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse?)?.statusCode
            //println("Status Code: \(statusCode), error: \(error)")
            if error != nil || (statusCode != 200 && statusCode != 201 && statusCode != 202){
                onCompletion(false, nil)

            } else {
                onCompletion(true, responseData)
            }
        })

        taskGetCategories.resume()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are sending the params as JSON while your API requires params as form data.

This code sends the params as simple form post and this retrieved successful response.

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://app123.freeiz.com/Apis/samples/api4.php")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
var postString =  ""
postString.append("function=value") // replace 'function' with your paramname and 'value' with your value'
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        if let unWrappedResponseString = responseString{

            print(unWrappedResponseString)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

I had once made a small wrapper for sending simple form data, If i find it I will update the answer with that. Till then you can try with this. Let me know how it goes..

Comment: You can use this wrapper [link](https://gist.github.com/PmAbi1993/06fbfb6a12607fc93d8d01b4e281c73f) for adding params and executing the request.

Comment: Interesting, so I was over-encoding it before sending rather than just doing it simply. Thank you for such a thorough answer, this worked perfectly and saved me hours.

Comment: Quick question. I am now receiving an error: Ambiguous reference to member 'resume(completion:)' When I add more params, any reason why this would occur?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out with some of my own old code. A problem with yours is that you can't do anything inside the completion handler except for print the function, which isnt very useful if the app is trying to do things with the info.

Comment: @Parker This was a small wrapper I made in one for my projects to send form data. We received only a JSON string as response and I modelled the class to just have the string passed to my thread. I think i should have updated it with more and have the whole data passed instead of just the response string.

But your original code is sufficient enough to handle network connections well. You can update here and there and the code can work better than the one I provided. I hope I was of help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your key is different use "function" instead of using "Function"

Comment: @GIJOW,   let params = ["function": "addUser"] as [String: AnyObject]?
and then he is trying to print(json["Function"].stringValue). So I assumed his key is different am I checking something wrong??

Comment: Yes. In his php he is reading 'function' and printing 'Function' and his json is taking the response 'Function' as printed from server. Or is too late and I'm missing something.

Comment: @GIJOW You are correct. The echoed json value from the server is Function and I am printing Function, but when requesting function is used.